# ROR: Paperclip styles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, resize, paperclip, thumbnails

I have a model that handles all my uploads of different filetypes.

- How do I create a style with the same name as the :basename so that the url will be the same for images and non-image files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to need to create a custom processor, then inside that processor you can call the IM methods for images and ignore the rest.

I didn't put much research into it, but this link might get you headed in the right direction: http://thewebfellas.com/blog/2009/2/22/video-thumbnails-with-ffmpeg-and-paperclip

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :photo, 
      :styles => {
        :thumb => {"115x70>"},
        :orig => {"300x168>"} }
        ..
```

As long as you specify two different styles, it'll create two different styles associated with your Upload object.

Then you can call them via :

```
= image_tag @upload.photo.url(:thumb)
= image_tag @upload.photo.url(:orig)
```

Comment: EDIT: Fat fingered that last comment. I have "has_attached_file :attached" which could be any kind of file with a method that checks if it's an image or not. Could I simply use after_create? I want every model that has and upload to call a thumbnail to be processed unless it's not a photo.

Comment: This would be awesome if it wasn't for the fact that I have multiple file types on the same model.

Answer (score 0):

Huh?

http://rdoc.info/github/thoughtbot/paperclip/master/Paperclip/ClassMethods#has_attached_file-instance_method

> The thumbnails will be created when
>   the new file is assigned, but they
>   will not be saved until save is called
>   on the record. Likewise, if the
>   attribute is set to nil is called on
>   it, the attachment will not be deleted
>   until save is called. See the
>   Paperclip::Attachment documentation
>   for more specifics.

Comment: I need it to save images to one particular path with a particular naming scheme :class_files/:id/:style.extension but use  /:class_files/:id/:basename.:extension for non images. But they both need the same attribute on the model through has_attached_file.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a simple question, but are you sure you have ImageMagick installed properly? Most problems that I've ran in to happen because ImageMagick isn't compiled/installed correctly. If you watch the logs, Paperclip will hum along and silently fail.

Comment: Yup! I can make thumbs, but the issue is when it hits a file that isn't an image and tries to make thumbs.